# ClickOnce Deployment -Could not find files

Tags: winforms, clickonce

I am still having issues deploying my app to the remote ftp server. This time, when user clicks to set up, simiar pop up error to contact admin shows up but the error is that files are not found. How do I fix this problem please?

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.17626
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.17626 built by: FX45RCREL
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.17626 built by: FX45RCREL
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.17626 built by: FX45RCREL
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41208.0 (Main.041208-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/CONCE/Downloads/AFDBFrontEnd.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\CONCE\Downloads\AFDBFrontEnd.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading file:///C:/Users/CONCE/Downloads/AFDBFrontEnd.application did not succeed.
        + Could not find file 'C:\Users\CONCE\Downloads\AFDBFrontEnd.application'.
        + Could not find file 'C:\Users\CONCE\Downloads\AFDBFrontEnd.application'.
        + Could not find file 'C:\Users\CONCE\Downloads\AFDBFrontEnd.application'.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [10/8/2012 9:58:22 AM] : Activation of C:\Users\CONCE\Downloads\AFDBFrontEnd.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [10/8/2012 9:58:22 AM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading file:///C:/Users/CONCE/Downloads/AFDBFrontEnd.application did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Could not find file 'C:\Users\CONCE\Downloads\AFDBFrontEnd.application'.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Could not find file 'C:\Users\CONCE\Downloads\AFDBFrontEnd.application'.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.IO.FileNotFoundException
        - Could not find file 'C:\Users\CONCE\Downloads\AFDBFrontEnd.application'.
        - Source: mscorlib
        - Stack trace:
            at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
            at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)
            at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had an error like this that was stumping me for the better part of the afternoon. I was trying to launch the app from Firefox.

Once I tried to deploy from the link using Internet Explorer, everything worked great.